# Strange slowdown on iMac 5,1

Tags: lubuntu, mac

I've had a strange slowdown I can't explain.

Setup: iMac 5,1: 2.16 GHz Core 2 Duo with 4 GB RAM. It's basically stock, except I put in an SSD. Set up as dual boot for MacOS 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) and Lubuntu 18.04

If I run the Lubuntu either from the CDROM or the first time I install, it works great. However, after doing a software update (either from the GUI or doing sudo apt-get update etc) and rebooting, the desktop becomes painfully slow. The pointer is jittery, all processes take a super long time. I can't figure out how to fix this.

One clue: If I boot into recovery mode, it seems to work fine, but only if I boot into 5.3, not 5.4

Comment: Why not use the GA (non-HWE) kernel, ie. 4.15 (which has security fixes back-ported to it).  It doesn't solve the issue directly, but you're hardly using *state of the art* equipment and need 2019 & 2020 kernel modules...

Comment: `apt update` only updates the list of available software.  You need to run `sudo apt upgrade` afterwards to actually update your system.  Maybe the system is slow because it's working on unattended upgrades (because maybe you didn't actually update your software when you thought you did)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's completed updating; I did do the upgrade after update. As to the GA kernel, what is that?

Comment: Ubuntu offers two kernel stack choices, GA or the general kernel refers to the default as provided on original & first subsequent ISO. The alternative is the HWE or hardware enablement stack kernel, which causes a 18.04 system to use firstly 18.10's (4.18) stack, then 19.04's (5.0), then 19.10's (5.3), before finally settlting on the next GA kernel or 20.04's or 5.4 stack.   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack  (HWE is default if you install with 18.04.2 or later ISOs for desktop)

Comment: FYI:  If asking a question of someone, you need to refer to them by @guiverc type of name, I'm only monitoring this question because of Lubuntu reference (unless GA kernel was geared for someone else...)